# Check auto-negotiated NIC speed on OpenBSD

Tags: performance, networking, openbsd, ifconfig

How do I check the auto-negotiated speed of a network interface on OpenBSD?
When I force a specific speed, ifconfig will show it in the "media" line; but if the interface is in auto-negotiation mode, I can't find a way to retrieve the network speed effectively negotiated.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If auto-negotiation is successful, you should also see it on the *media* line:

```
media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT full-duplex,master,rxpause,txpause)
```

The lack of the above output, or the need to force a particular speed, may indicate you have another problem (..bad cable; unsupported interface or hardware issue).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but my media line just shows "media: Ethernet autoselect", nothing more. It's a KVM virtual machine, so no bad cables, hardware problems or unsupported NIC. The SIOCGIFMEDIA syscall returns IFM_AUTO, so no information on link speed. Any other suggestions? Thanks.